# How to extract hours from DataFrame/Series column of timedelta objects?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

My series `s` looks something that looks like:

```
0   0 days 09:14:29.142000
1   0 days 00:01:08.060000
2   1 days 00:08:40.192000
3   0 days 17:52:18.782000
4   0 days 01:56:44.696000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to pull out the hours (rounded to the nearest hour)

Edit:

I realize I can do something like `s[0].hours`, which gives me `9L`. So I can do `s[0].hours + 24*s[0].days` and then round accordingly using the minutes.

How I can do this on the entire series at once?

Comment: Have you already tried some code? How would you like to round the hours: 09:14 becomes 9 or 10?

Comment: I have edited my post. I would like 09:14 to become 9., 9:33 to become 10, for example.

Comment: For rounding, maybe just add 30 minutes then do ```s[0].hours```?  As far as applying to the whole series, just leave off the ```[0]```.

Comment: Yes, I can handle the rounding now, I just don't understand how to the operation on the entire series at once.

Answer (score 3):

This is right out of the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#attributes). And this is vectorized.

```
In [16]: s
Out[16]: 
0   0 days 09:14:29.142000
1   0 days 00:01:08.060000
2   1 days 00:08:40.192000
3   0 days 17:52:18.782000
4   0 days 01:56:44.696000
Name: 0, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [17]: s.dt.components      
Out[17]: 
   days  hours  minutes  seconds  milliseconds  microseconds  nanoseconds
0     0      9       14       29           142             0            0
1     0      0        1        8            60             0            0
2     1      0        8       40           192             0            0
3     0     17       52       18           782             0            0
4     0      1       56       44           696             0            0

In [18]: s.dt.components.hours
Out[18]: 
0     9
1     0
2     0
3    17
4     1
Name: hours, dtype: int64
```

Here's another way to approach this if you don't need the actual hours attribute, but the Timedelta in terms of another unit (this is called frequency conversion)

```
In [31]: s/pd.Timedelta('1h')
Out[31]: 
0     9.241428
1     0.018906
2    24.144498
3    17.871884
4     1.945749
dtype: float64

In [32]: np.ceil(s/pd.Timedelta('1h'))
Out[32]: 
0    10
1     1
2    25
3    18
4     2
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This shows the hours truncated, not rounded. You're going to need some additional logic if you want to actually round using the fractional hours (i.e. the minutes, seconds, and sub seconds).

Comment: you can use .round() if that's the case

Comment: Sorry, not understanding. What would you use `.round()` on? `.round()`  doesn't seem to be an available method of `s`, `s.dt`, or `s.dt.components`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your time delta column there is called "Delta". Then you can do it this way:

```py
df['rh'] = df.Delta.apply(lambda x: round(pd.Timedelta(x).total_seconds() \
                          % 86400.0 / 3600.0) )
```

Each time delta is really a `numpy.timedelta64` under the covers. It helps to cast it to a pandas `Timedelta` which has more convenient methods. Here I just ask for the number of total seconds, lop off any multiples of 86400 (i.e. numbers that indicate full days), and divide by 3600 (number of seconds in an hour). That gives you a floating point number of hours, which you then round.

[image: dataframe after update]

I assumed, btw, that you wanted just the hour, minutes, seconds, and partial seconds components considered in the rounded hours, but not the full days. If you want *all* the hours, including the days, just omit the modulo operation that lops off days:

```py
df['rh2'] = df.Delta.apply(lambda x: round(pd.Timedelta(x).total_seconds() \
                           / 3600.0) )
```

Then you get:

[image: alternate update]

It's also possible to do these calculations directly in numpy terms:

```py
df['rh'] = df.Delta.apply(lambda x: round(x / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')) % 24 )
df['rh2'] = df.Delta.apply(lambda x: round(x / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')) )
```

Where `np.timedelta64(1, 'h')` provides the number of nanoseconds in 1 hour, and the optional `% 24` lops off whole day components (if desired).